# Element creation in space

Tags: cosmology, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, elements

In my astronomy magazine I recently saw the periodic system revisited where the elememnts were color-coded according to their production site. For example, Hydrogen was created from the early Universe simply existing but for Gold to exist we need the merger of neutron stars. 
My question: how can one calculate where these elements are created? I find it odd that e.g. Manganese is created in the explosion of white dwarfs.

Comment: I could copy this as an answer, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/nucsyn.html it explains the differences .

Comment: You may wish to browse the [nucleosynthesis](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nucleosynthesis) questions on the Astronomy Stack Exchange.